# What is the closure of the circal in this topology?

Tags: general-topology

cI have this topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ $$\sigma=\big\{\emptyset,\{(3,0)\}\big\}\cup\big\{\bigcup_{a\in A}\Omega_a :  A\subseteq \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}\big\}$$

where $$\Omega_a=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y-ax+3a=0\},\Omega_{\infty}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x=3\}$$

I need to find the adherence of the $C=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=4\}$

I see that

- $(3,0)\notin \rm cl\{C\}$
- the two lines $\Omega_{\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}$ and $\Omega_{\dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}}$ are tangent to C, so 
  $$\forall (x,y)\in \big[ \bigcup_{\dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}\leq a\leq \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}\Omega_a\big]\setminus\{(3,0)\}, (x,y)\in \rm cl\{C\}$$
- $C\subset \rm cl\{C\}$

Is it true if i say that $$\rm cl\{C\}=C\cup \big[ \bigcup_{\dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}\leq a\leq \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}\Omega_a\big]\setminus\{(3,0)\}$$

Comment: Good job. Set $a_0=2/\sqrt{5}$. All points in $C$ are included in $\bigcup_{-a_0\leq a\leq a_0}\Omega_a$ so that the closure of $C$ looks $\bigcup_{-a_0\leq a\leq a_0}\Omega_a\setminus\{(3,0)\}$.

Comment: so we don't need C right?, How to prove that $\bigcup_{-a_0\leq a\leq a_0}\Omega_a\setminus\{(3,0)\}$ is closed please

Comment: Let us show that the complement of $\overline{C}=\bigcup_{-a_0\leq a\leq a_0}\Omega_a\setminus{(3,0)}$ is open. For any $z\notin\overline{C}$, It suffices to find an open set $U_z$ containing $z$ but $U_z\cap\overline{C}=\varnothing$. If $z=(3,0)$, just choose $U_z=\{(3,0)\}$, then OK. Otherwise, since $z\notin\overline{C}$, you can find a line $U_z=\Omega_b$ passing through $z$ for some $b>a_0$ or $b<-a_0$. Therefore $\overline{C}$ is closed.